# How to order on a field based on how far to the left it occurs in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am attempting to use the Elasticsearch Java API to search for documents with a field containing the search term and then ordering the results based on how far to the left the term occurs in the fields value.

This is how I am creating the index:

```java
final CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("index-name");
request.settings(Settings.builder().put("index.max_result_window", MAX_RESULTS));
client.admin().indices().create(request).actionGet();
```

This is how I am creating the mapping:

```
{
  "part": {
    "properties":{
      "PartNumber":{
        "type":"keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I am querying Elasticsearch:

```java
final CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("index-name");
request.settings(Settings.builder().put("index.max_result_window", MAX_RESULTS));
client.admin().indices().create(request).actionGet();
client.admin()
      .indices()
      .preparePutMapping("index-name")
      .setType("part")
      .setSource(source, XContentType.JSON).execute().actionGet();

final SearchResponse searchResponse = elasticClient.getClient()
                .prepareSearch("index-name")
                .setQuery(boolQuery().must(wildcardQuery("PartNumber", "*five*")))
                .addSort("PartNumber", SortOrder.DESC)
                .setTypes("part")
                .get();
```

Which returns the results in the following order:

```
three five six four five four 11
five 11 three 2 three five four threefive
11 22 three fourfive five four
1 22 three four six five
```

However, the order I would like them to be in is:

```
five 11 three 2 three five four threefive
three five six four five four 11
11 22 three fourfive five four
1 22 three four six five
```

Where it orders them based on how far to the left of the value the term `five` occurs, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

First, try not to use [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) query. They are not efficient, particularly if you are using `keyword` fields with long text.

If you are using wildcards queries to match `five` in the text `fourfive`, you should use an [`ngram` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html).

That said, the position of the tokens are not taken into account to compute the score. There is no easy way that I know of to order the documents considering the positions of the tokens.

One solution could be to use multiple [`span_first`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-span-first-query.html) queries wrapped in a should query with varying `end` parameter. A token appearing in first position would then match more queries than one appearing on second position, etc.